# Using R Shiny checkboxGroupInput is there a way to remove [1] that appears in the textbox below the checkbox group (See image below for illustration)

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

I have this code to create a checkbox group:

```
column(4,checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup2", label = ("Must select one or more Transaction Types(s):"), choices = list("Sale", "Refund", "Exchange"),selected=c("Sale","Refund","Exchange"))
```

what I get is this:

[image: Check box group]

I want to remove the `[1]` that shows to the left of the items being selected. Is anyone aware of how this can be removed?

I switched to textOutput and now I'm getting  this:

[image]

I changed the ui to this:

```
column(4,
    checkboxGroupInput(
        "checkGroup2", 
        label = ("Must select one or more Transaction Types(s):"), 
        choices = list("Sale", "Refund", "Exchange"), 
        selected=c("Sale","Refund","Exchange"), 
        textOutput("value3"))
```

the server file shows this:

```
output$value3 <- renderPrint({ input$checkGroup2})
```

Any more ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing \[1\] with sink and sprintf output in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798330/removing-1-with-sink-and-sprintf-output-in-r)

Comment: It's printing the R console so you can't just remove the `[1]` but you could dynamically generate HTML of the text and make it look however you want.

Comment: Use `textOutput` instead of `verbatimTextOutput`. It has nothing to do with the input.

Comment: @alistaire I tried changing it to textOutput and now I view the second image above. Would you mind taking a look. I think youre close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
 library(shiny) 


shinyApp( 
  ui = fluidPage(

    mainPanel(column(4,checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup2", label = ("Must select one or more Transaction Types(s):"), choices = list("Sale", "Refund", "Exchange"),selected=c("Sale","Refund","Exchange")),
                     uiOutput("test")))), 

  server = function(input, output,session) { 


    output$test <- renderUI({
      req(input$checkGroup2)

      text <- paste0(input$checkGroup2,collapse=", ")

      tagList(HTML(text))

    })

  }
)
```

Edit: textOutput works the exact same way

```
 library(shiny) 


shinyApp( 
  ui = fluidPage(

    mainPanel(column(4,checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup2", label = ("Must select one or more Transaction Types(s):"), choices = list("Sale", "Refund", "Exchange"),selected=c("Sale","Refund","Exchange")),
                     textOutput("test")))), 

  server = function(input, output,session) { 


    output$test <- renderText({
      req(input$checkGroup2)

      paste0(input$checkGroup2,collapse=", ")          
    })

  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`textOutput` renders text as part of the page. Don't include it as part of the `checkboxGroupInput`. In a simple page:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup2", 
                     label = "Must select one or more Transaction Types(s):", 
                     choices = c("Sale", "Refund", "Exchange"),
                     selected = c("Sale","Refund","Exchange")),
  textOutput('checked')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$checked <- renderText(input$checkGroup2)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```